# How to populate vuetify hardcoded / Static select options HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, select, vue.js

How to populate vuetify hardcoded / Static select options HTML?

I am using this in asp.net based Vue app

```
<v-select label="Last Modified" 
:options="[{{label: 'foo', value: 'Foo'}}]">
</v-select>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question/problem ?

Comment: He does not want to use variable.

Answer (score 1):

`:options` accepts an array, e.g.

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

or an array with objects having a text and value prop

```
[{text: 'foo', value: 'a'}, {text: 'var', value: 'b'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
<v-select :items="['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz']"></v-select>
```